# Azure Service Bus queue with priority AND Handling docker containers to process the queue messages

Tags: c#, python, azure, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a question regarding service bus queue mechanism. I have to set up docker containers to run different python scripts. Each scripts does one specific image analysis process. Some of them are clustered.
Now my  ***problem*** is:

1) Python scripts must read messages from queue. There should be no conflict if 2 container trying to pull a message from same queue. **Is there any guide so I can follow for best practice setting up such a scenario?**
I still not sure how to cluster this separate scripts over one image but I am handling this clustering with .yml compose file.

2) And beside that there must be a **priority queue**. My messages must be set inside C# codes in priority and my python needs to process this messages. And I need a sophisticated logic that would throttle messages of the same priority giving a chance for other messages to get processed too even if there is a peak of high priority requests.

Hope this is clear. Can someone guide me in this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would start my looking at the api provided with the azure module that's on pypi.  All of your worker containers will be listening on the queue for messages of work to process.  I would write the code that processes these messages to do certain things based on the format of the message.  Since it looks like the workers can do different tasks.  This will enable you to have the same image for all of your worker containers.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks for your answer. But the thing is I was thinking of having different queues for processes but still each process will have for example 2 docker worker to listen on their same queue. Can u be a bit specific about this api I didn't find any more details. I am so sorry I have 2 more question. Do you have any suggestion regarding the priority? And normally we put CMD to run .py at the end of dockerfile what if i have more .py under same image and i want at start up each different docker container one specific script be running. any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding and per my experience, for your scenario, I think the best practice is only using a Service Bus Queue for these messages with priority property and create an application to receive these messages to add the related tasks to the different priority Python job to handle  on Azure Batch Service, not using different priority queues and handling Python jobs on Docker container.

You can refer to the offical [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-run-python) of Azure Batch Service for Python to know it, and the batch job has the priority property to satisfy your needs (Please search the keyword `priority` from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/batchservice/job/add)).

Hope it helps.

Comment: the link is no longer available.

Comment: @inquisitive Updated. Thanks.